# Testing javascript functions without exports

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, gulp

I've recently inherited a project which follows a unique way for creating client side javascript.

It has 3 javascript files as following:

```
Importer.js

class Importer() {
   static function importFrom() { ... }
}
```

```
Exporter.js

class Exporter() {
   static function exportTo() { ... }
}
```

```
Utils.js

class Utils() {
   static function convertFormat() { ... }
}
```

It uses a `gulp` task to concat everything in one file at the end which is being referenced in the front end.

I want to write unit tests for `Importer.js`,`Exporter.js`, `Utils.js`. But they don't have any export statements as they all are concated into one file and don't need export statements. Adding exports on the files breaks the existing functionality as they're not imported as modules.

Can anyone suggest a way how can I write unit tests for these 3 files without modifying the existing files?

Comment: Unit test against the file output by the gulp task?

Comment: The output file contains a lot of other things as well. I simplified the problem for SO question. Some code in the output file is looking for browser native functionality which is not available when running unit tests for console. Therefore running test from console errors out.